# Android with facebook integration shows misconfigured error

Tags: android, facebook

I have a simple code as below :

```
package com.my_fb_app2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;




public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Facebook facebook = new Facebook("118649691627381");
AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {}

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

Running keytool and giving password gives me hash as : LlpxIc8nZd7s3uwvfBffXiIoJrQ= which I have saved in my facebook app.

When i run this on emulator program runs as inteded i.e. ask for login info and then after authenticating displays hello world ! But when i run this on my galaxy s3 opening the app shows following page. screenshot provided here http://msu-footprints.org/2011/Aditya/screen.jpg

Comment: I guess your `hashkey` us wrong. Try to regenerate it..

Comment: Mohsin : Tried several times. After giving password as 'android' it generates the same key which I am copying into facebook app

Answer (score 0):

Your emulator most probably doesn't have the Facebook app installed, that's why it works (it uses the web view instead). Anyways, if you are getting this error, it means that your code is ok, and the app's preferences at Facebook are somehow misconfigured. My guess is that the app's hashkey is generated incorrectly. You could try generating it for another keystore and signing the app with that keystore

Comment: what do you mean by another keystore ? I run the following command in my bin directory of jdk
`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\Aditya\.android\debug.keystore | "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary | "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\bin\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin\openssl" base64`

Comment: @aditya Here's some information on that topic http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html . You can go to "File->Export->Export Android application" and create a new keystore and its alias there (as well as export an apk signed with that certificate). After that your command will changeto : [...] -alias your_alias_name -keystore C:\Users\Aditya\.android\your_key_name.keystore [...]

Answer (score 0):

was using open ssl 32 bit version for my 64 bit computer which created a wrong hash key.